# Remote json and Javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm currently developing a web application for the school where I work. We have a program called FROG on one of our dedicated servers. Unfortunately this is very locked down, and you create websites using a a gui. The most coding you can do on it is HTML and javascript.

I want to be able to retrieve information from a remote server which we also own. I cant use ajax due to the cross domain restrictions. However I have come up with a work around.

I have this function call on my remote server within a file called xrequest.js:

```
loadNotices({[{title: 'this is a test'},{title: 'this is another test'}]});
```

This is simply a function call with a json object passed as an argument (The argument will ultimately be generated from data retrieved from a database).

On my other restricted server, I have this javacript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadNotices(data)
{
    alert(data);
}

var url = "http://somedomain.com/tests/xrequest.js";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', url);

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
</script>
<div id="notices"></div>
```

What I want to do is loop through each of the titles in the xrequest.js file, and display them as a list.

Im unsure how to loop through the titles.

If you need any more information, please leave a comment. Any help is appriciated.

Many thanks

Phil

Comment: Can you show us `xrequest.js`? If you have all of the titles in an array, you need a `for` loop.

Comment: The code in `xrequest.js` is not valid JavaScript, it will throw an error. Remove the outer `{ ... }` so that you have an array of objects. Then simply iterate over that array and access each object's `title` property. How to work with objects is covered here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects. Also note that the argument passed to `loadNotices` is not JSON.

Comment: Hi starbeamrainbowlabs, the only line of code contained in xrequest.js is the function call loadNotices({[{title: 'this is a test'},{title: 'this is another test'}]});  I have tried a for loop, however all I can get alerted is either [object] or undefined.

Comment: Hi Felix, I have adjusted the code to remove the outer '{}', and then created a for(title in data) loop, however when I alert(title); it alerts either 0 or 1.

Comment: Which is correct since the array has two elements at index `0` and `1`. Never use `for...in` to iterate over an array, use a normal `for` loop. Also have a look at the link I posted. How to iterate over arrays and access objects should be covered in every JavaScript tutorial, [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) is worth a read.

Comment: Hi Felix, Thats worked thanks :) Also, thanks for the link, i'll be giving it a read over this afternoon!

Answer (score 1):

To loop over the titles, you first need to remove the curly braces around your array. After, loop through the titles like below:

```
function loadNotices(arr) {
    var title, i = 0;
    for (; i < arr.length; i++) {
        title = arr[i].title;
    }
}​
```

Also, look into changing:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

to

```
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation look like JSONP call. With Jquery you can make it easy

```
$.get('url?callback', {<data>}, function(data){

});
```

with `?callback` at the end of url, jquery auto create a random callback function. At your server instead of return normal JSON, you can add wraper callback function around it.
example with php:

```
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
echo $callback.'('.json_encode(obj).');';
```

which will become

```
callback({your return data>});
```

and your script will receive that.

```
loadNotices({[{title: 'this is a test'},{title: 'this is another test'}]});
```

this function call is not correct, do this instead:

```
loadNotices([{title: 'this is a test'},{title: 'this is another test'}]);
```

then you can loop through your title like this

```
for (i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
   alert(titles[i].title);
}
```